# Ruby on rails changes not reflecting after editing user's details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am Rails newbie. I am creating a section that is pulling existing user's details and when the user click on edit, he can save the changes he has made. However, the changes aren't reflecting once the user saves it. Can you tell me what I am missing in here?

Here's the html/ruby form I am using:

```
  <%= form_tag(html: {:id => 'user_profile_form'}, :url => patient_profile_path(@user), :method => :put) do %>
     <%= text_field_tag(:inputFieldName, "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}", {:disabled => true}) %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Save', :id=> 'saveButton' %>
  <%= end %>
```

Here's the routes:

```
  put :patient_profile, to: 'users#patient_profile'
  post :dashboard, to: 'dashboard#index'
```

Here are the controller codes:

```
   def patient_profile
    if params[:user]
      u = params[:user]
      @user.first_name = u[:first_name] unless u[:first_name].nil? || u[:first_name].empty?
      @user.last_name = u[:last_name] unless u[:last_name].nil? || u[:last_name].empty?
      @user.save!
      # index
      render :index
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is the record not being updated?

Comment: I am not receiving any errors, just the data isn't getting modified

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your form is actually updating anything since your form fields don't match your model. Try simplifying your form action:

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@user, html: {:id => 'user_profile_form'}, :url => patient_profile_path(@user), :method => :put) do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
     <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
     <%= f.submit "Update User" %>
  <%= end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
  def patient_profile
      # TODO: Handle failed validation
      @user.update_attributes!(params[:user])

      # index
      render :index
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end
```

Comment: Anthony, I have a single field for the user's name, like below:                                                <%= text_field_tag(:inputFieldName, "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}", {:disabled => true}) %>                                                            How can I integrate your way into this?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's setting the params in the controller. Are you seeing params for the user's name in the logs?

Comment: I do have these in my user's controller as private methods:                     def patient_profile_params
    params.tab do |p|
      p.permit(:first_name)
      p.permit(:last_name)
      p.permit(:date_of_birth)
      p.permit(:diabetes_type)
      p.permit(:a1c_reading)
    end
  end